# What is the encoding used for Khmer Language

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I want to know what encoding is used for [Khmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khmer_language) Language (Official language of Cambodia). Is it `UTF-8` or `UTF-16`.

Comment: I like the "is it UTF-8 or UTF-16" part of the question.  In the late 1990s a company called "ABC Computers" produced a Khmer font with their own 1-byte encoding, which had to be specially selected because it wasn't a standard "code page".  Be glad you don't have to deal with that nowadays ☺

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A language doesn't have an encoding. What it might have is a set of characters that are commonly used when writing in that language. Some encodings only support subsets of Unicode, but both UTF-8 and UTF-16 can encode all Unicode characters, so either will work (i.e. will allow you to represent anything in Unicode) if you have the ability to choose which to use. (If you want characters which aren't in Unicode, neither UTF-8 nor UTF-16 is going to help you.)

I would typically use UTF-8 as a default - pretty much every platform supports UTF-8, whereas UTF-16 is *slightly* less well supported. On the other hand, you *may* find that there are lots of characters used by Khmer which take two bytes to encode in UTF-16 but three bytes in UTF-8, making UTF-8 take a bit more space. You should investigate this by encoding sample documents in both encodings *if* space is important to you.

Comment: As Khmer's Unicode range is U+1780 through U+17FF, all Khmer characters take 3 bytes in UTF-8.  But it compresses well, and UTF-8 has the advantage of being self-synchronising as well as being more widely supported.  Also, if you are mixing Khmer with markup like HTML (encoded in ASCII), and if there's lots of markup, then the UTF-8 option may result in an overall smaller size even without compression, since UTF-16 would require even the ASCII parts to be 2-byte encoded.  That's probably why Khmer websites like [Rasmei News](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasmei_Kampuchea_Daily) use UTF-8.